# Powermockito private method mock NullPointerException. Calls the private method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermockito

I'm trying to mock a private method (executeGetRequest) and in the line that I'm declaring the mock that I want returned for the private method, the private method is actually being executed with null arguments, therefore throwing a NullPointerException.

VlcPlayerMinimal.java:

```
package com.nicobrest.kamehouse.vlcrc.model;

public class VlcPlayerMinimal {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String vlcRcStatus = new VlcPlayerMinimal().getVlcRcStatus();
    System.out.println(vlcRcStatus);
  }

  public String getVlcRcStatus() {
    Client client = new Client();
    GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest();
    String vlcRcStatus = executeGetRequest(client, getRequest);
    return vlcRcStatus;
  }

  private String executeGetRequest(Client client, GetRequest getRequest) {
    return client.execute(getRequest);
  }

  private class Client {
    public String execute(GetRequest getRequest) {
      return "{status: playing, id: 1}";
    }
  }
  private class GetRequest { 
  }
}
```

VlcPlayerMinimalTest.java:

```
package com.nicobrest.kamehouse.model;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

import com.nicobrest.kamehouse.vlcrc.model.VlcPlayerMinimal;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

public class VlcPlayerMinimalTest {

  @Test
  public void getVlcRcStatusTest() {
    VlcPlayerMinimal vlcPlayerSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new VlcPlayerMinimal());
    try {
      PowerMockito.doReturn("{status: stopped, id: 2}").when(vlcPlayerSpy, "executeGetRequest", any(), any());
      String vlcRcStatus = vlcPlayerSpy.getVlcRcStatus();
      System.out.println(vlcRcStatus);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      fail("Unexpected exception thrown.");
    }
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nicobrest.kamehouse.vlcrc.model.VlcPlayerMinimal.executeGetRequest(VlcPlayerMinimal.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1846)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:810)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:675)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:95)
    at com.nicobrest.kamehouse.model.VlcPlayerMinimalTest.getVlcRcStatusTest(VlcPlayerMinimalTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

It appears PowerMockito is actually calling the method that I'm trying to mock in the line  PowerMockito.doReturn("{status: stopped, id: 2}").when(vlcPlayerSpy, "executeGetRequest", any(), any());

And it's throwing the exception because client is null, so it's calling execute(getClient) on null, but that's the method I'm trying to avoid to call in the test.

Any ideas how to fix this? I've been trying for a while without success.

I'm using Java 8, powermock 1.7.3 and junit 4.12

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test getVlcRcStatus in the VlcPlayer class, that calls the VLC web API and then I generate my custom status object. (I can post the whole code if needed). I will add validations to the test case after the call to vlcPlayerSpy.getVlcRcStatus(); once I get it working. I wrapped the call to the web API of VLC in the private method executeGetRequest to mock that API call and test the rest of my code.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Thank you RC. I replaced the example code I had put before with a minimal, complete and verifiable example that replicates the same issue with just one class and it's test case

Comment: I think the issue is `@PrepareForTest(xxx)` is missing on the test class

Comment: Thank you RC!! That was the issue. I also had to add @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class). In my real case I'm having trouble now when trying to mock apache HttpResponse.class and HttpEntity.class, but your comment solves the issue posted in the question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This Test is Succesful:**

```
package foo.bar;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(VlcPlayerMinimal.class)
public class VlcPlayerMinimalTest {

  @Test
  public void getVlcRcStatusTest() {
    VlcPlayerMinimal vlcPlayerSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new VlcPlayerMinimal());
    try {
      PowerMockito.doReturn("{status: stopped, id: 2}").when(vlcPlayerSpy, "executeGetRequest", Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
      String vlcRcStatus = vlcPlayerSpy.getVlcRcStatus();
      System.out.println(vlcRcStatus);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      fail("Unexpected exception thrown.");
    }
  }
}
```

**You need these Class Level Annotations:**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(VlcPlayerMinimal.class)
```

**Console Output:**

> {status: stopped, id: 2}

[image]